# SAP Hybris B2b 1905 Sample yb2bacceleratorstorefront url not opening

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

B2bStorefrontModule is not included in latest version. could you please suggest me how to add this module in app.module.ts with hybris 1905 version.

Answer (score 1):

The B2B features are on the Spartacus roadmap. See https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/spartacus-roadmap/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.